# Wrong swipe direction js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please tell me, if you start touchmove from the middle of the page and move to the right, then console.log() goes right, but if you move to the left and cross the middle of the screen, console.log() will show the opposite direction, although the swipe goes in the same direction. As I understand it, this is due to the fact that touchstart coordinates are fixed from where touchmove started. How to fix this error. (see video).

https://youtu.be/_pB49S2BR2o

```js
var initialX = null;
var initialY = null;
$("#content, .menu").on("touchstart", function(e) {
  initialX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;
});
$("#content, .menu").on("touchmove", function(e) {
  var diffX = initialX - e.touches[0].clientX;
  var diffY = initialY - e.touches[0].clientY;

  if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
    if (diffX > 0) {
      console.log("Right");
    } else {
      console.log("Left");
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
  var width = parseInt($("body").css("width"));
  clientX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  width = width - clientX;
  if (width >= 0 || width <= 375) {
    $(".menu").css("left", "-" + width + "px");
  } else {}
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.menu {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<body>
  <div class="menu" style="transition-duration: 0ms;">Menu slide</div>
  <div id="content">
    Content slide
  </div>
</body>
```

```
const text = document.querySelector('#direction');
const cursorEl = document.querySelector('#cursorDir');

let lastX = null;
let active = false;
$("#content, .menu").on("touchstart", function(evt) {
    active = true; 
});
$("#content, .menu").on("touchend", function(evt) {
    active = false; 
});

$("#content, .menu").on("touchmove", function(evt) {
    if (!active) return; // Run only on mousedown
    if (lastX === null) {
      // Set first value
      lastX = evt.clientX;
      return;
    }
    const diff = lastX - evt.clientX;
    if (diff === 0) return; // Break if there's 0 pixels difference
    console.log("direction: " + (diff > 0 ? "Left" : "Right"));
    lastX = evt.clientX; // Set next value to check the difference
});
```

Comment: What is your exact error? What did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: @Ron The problem is the wrong input in which direction the touchmove occurs (shown in the video)

Comment: Your reference is touchstart, if you need to know if the element is swiped to one direction, you need the element position as reference. If on the other hand, you need to have the cursor direction, you need the last touchmove position

Comment: The problem here is that we don't understand what you want the result to be, that's why I provided two solutions but this question is unclear on whether you want the cursor to dectect direction or the element direction. Your video shows, as your code, that the Right/Left output depends on where you STARTED to swipe, the problem is that we don't see why you consider that a problem. What are you trying to have as result?

Comment: @savageGoat What you need to get is that if we started moving from the center of the screen to the right, and then started moving to the left, went beyond the place where we started, it should display to the left, not to the right.

Comment: What you need to get is that Right or Left are values that refer to the start of the touch, not the direction of your move but the relative distance between the start of the touch and the current position of the touch

Comment: @savageGoat In a nutshell, currently the correct output occurs when we cross the touchmove start point.

Comment: Yes, we can all agree on that, that's what your code says. But again, it doesn't explain why you consider this a problem. What are you trying to have as what you consider as "good result"?

Comment: @savageGoat I want to get the direction of movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

**Note**: For the purpose of running this in a browser, `touchstart` and `touchmove` are replaced by `mousedown` and `mousemove`

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#direction');
const cursorEl = document.querySelector('#cursorDir');

let lastX = null;
let active = false;
cursorEl.addEventListener('mousedown', () => { active = true; });
document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => { active = false; });

cursorEl.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {
    if (!active) return; // Run only on mousedown
    if (lastX === null) {
      // Set first value
      lastX = evt.clientX;
      return;
    }
    const diff = lastX - evt.clientX;
    if (diff === 0) return; // Break if there's 0 pixels difference
    text.innerHTML = "direction: " + (diff > 0 ? "Left" : "Right");
    lastX = evt.clientX; // Set next value to check the difference
});
```

```css
#cursorDir {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#cursorDir {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
Click and hold to activate
<div id="cursorDir"></div>
<div id="direction"><div>
```

Comment: Can you make an example of my code?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work with touch. In console it always prints right. Added code to the question.

Comment: @Vector you are asking for a ready solution for your code. SO is not the place for this... The code in this answer works! And you should learn from it and then improve your code... not expect  to "make an example of your code"....

Comment: I'm talking about the fact that with the actions touchmove, touchstart, touchend does not work. What is the place or not place?